# Microsoft BizTalkServer 2010's custom SFTP adapter not compatible with the new version of SFTP

Tags: sftp, biztalk, compatibility, biztalk-2010

I am part of integration team of Microsoft. We work on BizTalk server tool. For SFTP transfers, a custom adapter code has been implemented to upload or download files to SFTP. Now the SFTP team has migrated the OS from 2008 to 2016. When we are trying to connect to the new version of SFTP, BizTalk fails to connect. Even the WinSCP, i had tried to connect. It was observed that, v5.7 and below fail to connect. Please suggest if anyone have any resolution for this.

Comment: What *new version of SFTP*? What error do you get? Show us some log files.

Comment: From this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a346b7e-6ebe-4662-93c1-749d6a862188/need-help-custom-sftp-adapter-in-biztalk-2010-uploading-the-files-intermittently?forum=biztalkgeneral  they are using a custom SFTP adapter based on TamirSSH

Comment: The SFTP team is using EFT server latest version 7.4. In the custom code of SFTP, Tamir.SharpSSH is being used. This is not compatible with the latest version of SFTP location. Will Renci.SSH.Net will help us resolve this issue? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

BizTalk 2010 is coming to end of life, and the database it uses, SQL Server 2008/R2 is already out of support.

Both these mean you really should be upgrading to BizTalk 2016, and with either CU6 or Feature Pack 3 with CU6 (update, should now upgrade to BizTalk 2020), would allow you to use the out of the box SFTP adapter.  CU6 fixes a lot of the issues with the out of the box SFTP adapter, plus it will be able to connect to a wider variety of SFTP servers.